# Clean URL for Azure Red Hat OpenShift Cluster

Tags: azure, openshift, redhat, aro

We created an Azure Red Hat OpenShift (ARO) cluster via:

```
az openshift create --resource-group $CLUSTER_NAME --name $CLUSTER_NAME -l $LOCATION --aad-client-app-id $APPID --aad-client-app-secret $SECRET --aad-tenant-id $TENANT --customer-admin-group-id $GROUPID
```

The URL for the cluster came out in the form:

```
https://openshift.<cluster-id>.<cluster-region>.azmosa.io/
```

Is there a way to give it a cleaner, human-readable URL like:

```
https://openshift.myprodcluster.<cluster-region>.azmosa.io/
```

Comment: That's for the web console? It's not likely that you can change it. You should however be able to create application routes with friendly URLs assuming you create the necessary DNS records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Will Gordon comment, I don't think you can change the default URL `https://openshift.<cluster-id>.<cluster-region>.azmosa.io/` provided by the Azure platform.

If you need a cleaner, human-readable URL, you could try to add a `CNAME` DNS record which maps your custom domain name like `www.contoso.com` to this hostname `openshift.<cluster-id>.<cluster-region>.azmosa.io` in your DNS provider.

If so, you will need to purchase a public domain and get an SSL certificate with that custom DNS name over a secure HTTPS connection. You also could get a free SSL certificate from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/).